# MAMP: mysql server doesn't start

Tags: mysql, mamp

I am aware that this has already been asked, however all the solutions I find in regards to killing the processes didn't work. It states that no processes were found.

Heres my MAMP log:

```
170116 12:01:22 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56
2017-01-16 12:01:23 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-01-16 12:01:23 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-01-16 12:01:23 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.34) starting as process 2413 ...
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size =  128.0M
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 19666195 and 19666195 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 20180371 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-01-16 12:01:23 2413 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/slave_worker_info uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./mysql/slave_worker_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace wp_dev/wp_devterm_taxonomy which uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./wp_dev/wp_devterm_taxonomy.ibd
2017-01-16 12:01:23 7fff7c867000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./wp_dev/wp_devterm_taxonomy.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170116 12:01:23 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
170116 13:21:35 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56
2017-01-16 13:21:36 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-01-16 13:21:36 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-01-16 13:21:36 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.34) starting as process 3435 ...
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 19666195 and 19666195 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 20180371 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-01-16 13:21:36 3435 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-01-16 13:21:37 3435 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/slave_worker_info uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./mysql/slave_worker_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace wp_dev/wp_devterm_taxonomy which uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./wp_dev/wp_devterm_taxonomy.ibd
2017-01-16 13:21:37 7fff7c867000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./wp_dev/wp_devterm_taxonomy.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170116 13:21:37 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Any help as to how to get this working again would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've had similar issues a few times. Maybe deleting log files could help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87692/flush-clean-mysql-ib-logfile0-ib-logfile1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue several times when MAMP crashed.
My solution:
Edit the mysql template under File -> Edit Template -> MySQL ->  , add following lines and restart MAMP:

```
# MYSQL server
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```